# How to run tests based on the day and corresponding tags

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a freestyle Jenkins job and need to execute different set of test cases based on the day. All those need to schedule at 8 AM EST daily.

Scenario:
I need to pass Build Parameters as below..

- Monday -Tests_Car
- Tuesday -Tests_Bus
- Wednesday -Tests_bicycle
- Thursday -Tests_Retail
- Friday -Tests_Payments

How can I pass these parameters dynamically based on the day?

Answer (score 1):

This plugin will suite your requirement

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Scheduler+Plugin